# Reading in Multiple Inputs (form)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a single `TextBox`, to be used to enter an integer. In the event the user enters multiple integers (either separated by a comma or not), how can I read them in separately?

Comment: Look up the documentation for `String.Split()` method.

Comment: I don't think a `String.Split()` alone will not be helpfull as Op needs to get the result into a `List<int>()` so a conversion also needed

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep that question is for Java. This is for C#/WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me name the TextBox as `txtInputNumber` and the input you ware giving in the textBox be "12,11,10"; You can convert it into a `List<Int>()` using the following code:

```
 List <int> myIntegers = txtInputNumber.Text.Split(',').Select(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList() ;
```

**Additional Notes :**

- The [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) method will help you to split up the string into an array/List based on the Delimiter (here `,`). which is basically a collection of string. your requirement is to get a collection of integers. you you need to convert each element in the collection to an integer.
- You need to check for a Valid String as input and ensure the delimiter should be `,` so you need to enclose the operations surrounded by a `try..catch`

So the snippet will looks like:

```
        try
        {
            List<int> myIntegers = txtInputNumber.Text.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
        }
        catch
        {
          // Display error here
          // Input is not valid; 
        }
```

Comment: I agree with this (+1), but what if the user entered something other than an integer?

Comment: Put me in the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
var inputString = txtIntegers.Text;
        List<int> integres = new List<int>();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString))
        {
            char[] inputChars = inputString.ToCharArray();
            int output = 0;
            foreach(char inputchar in inputChars)
            {
               bool conversionSuccess = int.TryParse(inputchar.ToString(), out output);
               if (conversionSuccess)
               {
                   integres.Add(output);
                   output = 0;
               }
            }
        }
```

> You can something like this. This will eliminate the invalid integers like characters or symbols. At the end, you will only get integers from the input.